# Reading a string character by character in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to read a string character by character in C. Since there is no string class, there are no functions to help this. Here is what i want to do: I have,

```
char m[80];  //I do some concenation, finally m is:

m= 12;256;2;
```

Now, i want to count how many characters are there between the semicolumns. In this example, there are 2,4 and 1 characters respectively. How can do this?

Thank you

Comment: This isn't valid C, and it doesn't do close to what you expect.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with my question, and why the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "there are no functions to help this"?  There are.  If you want to read a string, check out the function `fgets`.

On to the problem at hand, let's say you have this:

```
char m[80] = "12;256;2";
```

And you want to count the characters between the semi-colons.  The easiest way is to use `strchr`.

```
char *p = m;
char *pend = m + strlen(m);
char *plast;
int count;

while( p != NULL ) {
    plast = p;
    p = strchr(p, ';');

    if( p != NULL ) {
        // Found a semi-colon.  Count characters and advance to next char.
        count = p - plast;
        p++;
    } else {
        // Found no semi-colon.  Count characters to the end of the string.
        count = pend - p;
    }

    printf( "Number of characters: %d\n", count );
}
```

Comment: The other option is `strtok`, which is arguably better for this.

Comment: Well yeah.  I said easiest.  Maybe `strtok` is also (arguably) easier.  I generally don't encourage it because it's not thread-safe.  Not that thread-safety is the point in this exercise.  But fair enough comment.

Comment: Actually, when I think about it, `strtok` is not appropriate because it will eat adjacent delimiters.  If you had `12;256;;;2`, then `strtok` would not recognise the 0-length fields in what seems to be a CSV row.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not sure were supposed to write the code for you here, just correct it. But...

```
int strcount, charcount = 0, numcharcount = 0, num_char[10] = 0;  
                                            //10 or how many segments you expect

for (strcount = 0; m[strcount] != '\0'; strcount++) {

    if (m[strcount] == ';') {

         num_char[numcharcount++] = charcount;
         charcount = 0;             

    } else {

         charcount++;

    }

}
```

This will store the amount of each character between the `;` in an array.
It is kind of sloppy I'll admit but it will work for what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind modifying your string then the easiest way is to use `strtok`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char m[80] = "12;256;2;";
    char *p;

    for (p = strtok(m, ";"); p; p = strtok(NULL, ";"))
        printf("%s = %u\n", p, strlen(p));
}
```